# Замена букв в слове на цифры

Tags: java

Нужно заменить буквы в слове на цифры. Одна цифра может хранить в себе до 4 букв. Почему строка не меняется?

```
centerBut.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String fn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Введите имя: ");
        String fw1 = scan.next();
        fn.replace('а', '1');
        fn.replace('и', '1');
        fn.replace('с', '1');
        fn.replace('ъ', '1');
        fn.replace('б', '2');
        fn.replace('й', '2');
        fn.replace('т', '2');
        fn.replace('ы', '2');
        fn.replace('в', '3');
        fn.replace('к', '3');
        fn.replace('у', '3');
        fn.replace('ь', '3');
        fn.replace('г', '4');
        fn.replace('л', '4');
        fn.replace('ф', '4');
        fn.replace('э', '4');
        fn.replace('д', '5');
        fn.replace('м', '5');
        fn.replace('х', '5');
        fn.replace('ю', '5');
        fn.replace('е', '6');
        fn.replace('н', '6');
        fn.replace('ц', '6');
        fn.replace('я', '6');
        fn.replace('ё', '7');
        fn.replace('о', '7');
        fn.replace('ч', '7');
        fn.replace('ж', '8');
        fn.replace('п', '8');
        fn.replace('ш', '8');
        fn.replace('з', '9');
        fn.replace('р', '9');
        fn.replace('щ', '9');
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ваши числа " + fn, "window", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
});
```

Comment: вы знаете что строки неизменяемые в Java?.. присваивайте значение. И да, поменяйте компилятор/IDE если вам это не написало.

Comment: Незнание языка != причина закрытия.

Comment: да госпади если у тебя строка то делай так )

Comment: if (a.equals(""a)){

Comment: и вот тебе ождно  из тысычу решений )

Comment: Когда что-то не работает, первая задача — четко объяснить что именно и почему.

Answer (score 1):

Метод `replace` не меняет исходную строку, а возвращает новую строку. Соответственно, во всех строках кода должно быть так:

```
fn = fn.replace(...);
```

Однако создавать при каждой замене новую строку - не лучший подход. Можно проходить по всем символам строки, вычислять замещающий символ и добавлять его в `StringBuilder`, после чего создавать строку из `StringBuilder`.

Также 33 строки кода на замену - это много дублируемого кода. Стоит попытаться объединить символы в группы с заданными правилами замены. Например, так:

```
private static char replaceChar(char c)
{
    int resultCharCode = c;
    if (c >= 1072 && c <= 1077)
    {
        resultCharCode = c - 1023;
    }
    else if (c >= 1078 && c <= 1103)
    {
        resultCharCode = (c - 1071) % 9 + 49;
    }
    else if (c == 1105)
    {
        resultCharCode = c - 1050;
    }
    return (char)resultCharCode;
}
```

И, в итоге, использование:

```
String str = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (char c : str.toCharArray())
{
    char replacedChar = replaceChar(c);
    sb.append(replacedChar);
}
String result = sb.toString();
```

Вывод на экран `str` и `result` такой:

```
абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя
123456789123456789123456789123456
```